# Add exclusion to Windows defender from Real-time protection only

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

How do I add exclusions to file/folders from real-time protection only? I would like these files/folders to be scanned on scheduled scans but exclude from real-time protection. I know that other antiviruses have that option, I can't seem to find that for Windows Defender.

When adding them under "Exclusions" the description says that Defender will not scan the items in exclusions list. Here's the
[description of Exclusions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZoRZ.png)

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Excluding development folders from scans seems like a bad idea but I want my pacakages to install FAST and the Antimalware Service Executable takes up a lot of CPU during for instance a yarn or npm install.